# how to get start date of the week using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

I have another question, does any one know how to get the start date and end date of the current week?

Thanks very much.

Ling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())` will return the current day of week as an integer (Sunday=1, Saturday=7)

Simple math will take care of the rest.

- Saturday: `DATEADD(dd, 7 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), GETDATE())`
- Sunday: `DATEADD(dd, -1 * DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), GETDATE())`

Comment: What about those places on this planet earth where the week starts on MONDAY ??